# Parsing a single quotes json string clickhouse

Tags: sql, json, clickhouse

I have json  that needs to be parsed but the problem is that json's string values have a single quotes

```
{'name': None, 'medium': 'organic', 'source': 'google-play'}
```

Is there a way to parse this in clickhouse? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a single quote JSON, it's only a print format of JSON Dict.
But you can do this to convert it into a JSON:

```sql
SELECT JSONExtractString(
  replaceAll(
    replaceAll(
      '{''name'': None, ''medium'': ''organic'', ''source'': ''google-play''}', '''', '"'
    ), 'None', 'null'
  ), 'medium'
)
```